# Ponderate average MYSQL

Tags: mysql, dml

We have a little simulator of a tour-operator DB (MYSQL) and we are asked to get a Query that gives us the weighted avg of duration of the tours that we have.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean

Using subquery I got to this point where I have the days that each tour lasts and the weight of each tour from the total of tours, but I am stuck and don't know how to get the weighted avg from here. I know I have to use another select from the result I already got but I would appreciate some help.

SQLfiddle down here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d80/2

Tables and data

```
CREATE TABLE STAGE
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    TOUR INT NOT NULL,
    TYPE INT NOT NULL,
    CITY INT NOT NULL,
    DAYS INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TOUR
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI 
    NOT NULL,
    STARTED_ON DATE NOT NULL,
    TYPE INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO TOUR (DESCRIPTION, STARTED_ON, TYPE) VALUES 
('Mediterranian Cruise','2018-01-01',3),
('Trip to Nepal','2017-12-01',1),
('Tour in Nova York','2015-04-24',5),
('A week at the Amazones','2014-09-11',2),
('Visiting the Machu Picchu','2013-02-19',4);

INSERT INTO STAGE (TOUR, TYPE, CITY, DAYS) VALUES 
(1, 1, 38254, 1),
(1, 2, 22460, 3),
(1, 2, 47940, 3),
(1, 2, 42600, 4),
(1, 3, 38254, 1),
(2, 1, 13097, 1),
(2, 2, 29785, 5),
(2, 3, 13097, 1),
(3, 1, 788, 2); ,
(3, 2, 48019, 6),
(3, 3, 788, 1),
(4, 1, 38254, 2),
(4, 2, 8703, 3);,
(4, 3, 38254, 4),
(5, 1, 10453, 1),
(5, 2, 32045, 5),
(5, 3, 10453, 2);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    AVG(TD.TOUR_DAYS) AS AVERAGE_DAYS,
    COUNT(TD.TOUR_ID) AS WEIGHT
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TOUR.ID AS TOUR_ID, 
        SUM(DAYS) AS TOUR_DAYS,
        COUNT(STAGE.ID) AS STAGE_DAYS
    FROM
        TOUR
    INNER JOIN
        STAGE
    ON
        TOUR.ID = STAGE.TOUR
    GROUP BY
        TOUR.ID
) AS TD
GROUP BY 
    TD.TOUR_DAYS
```

weigthed avg would be:

 
 (1×7+1×8+2×9+1×12) / (1+1+2+1) = 9

Comment: It's nice that you've created a fiddle. But you should also post the sample data and your query in the question. Also post your expected result.

Comment: So what is the expected result? 9?

Comment: Yes, it would be 9

Comment: what does "ponderate" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wheighted AVG can be calculated with `SUM(value * wheight) / SUM(wheight)`. In your case:

```
SELECT SUM(AVERAGE_DAYS * WEIGHT) / SUM(WEIGHT)
FROM (
    SELECT
            AVG(TD.TOUR_DAYS) AS AVERAGE_DAYS,
            COUNT(TD.TOUR_ID) AS WEIGHT
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                TOUR.ID AS TOUR_ID, 
                SUM(DAYS) AS TOUR_DAYS,
                COUNT(STAGE.ID) AS STAGE_DAYS
            FROM
                TOUR
            INNER JOIN
                STAGE
            ON
                TOUR.ID = STAGE.TOUR
            GROUP BY
                TOUR.ID
        ) AS TD
        GROUP BY 
            TD.TOUR_DAYS
) sub
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d80/4

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like the following query is doing exactly the same:

```
SELECT AVG(TOUR_DAYS)
FROM (
  SELECT TOUR, SUM(DAYS) AS TOUR_DAYS
  FROM STAGE
  GROUP BY TOUR
) sub;
```

Or even without any subqueries:

```
SELECT SUM(DAYS) / COUNT(DISTINCT TOUR)
FROM STAGE;
```

That would mean, the requirement should be simplified to "Get average number of days per tour".

Comment: Wow, okay didn't think to do that, i did not know i could operate inside a function sum(). Thank you!

Comment: @PolVilarrasa Check the update. Seems that the requirement is overcomplicated.

Comment: definitely the result you get is the same, but the objective was to get the result using the Weighted averege formula. We already got the lasts two queries that you posted, but the task was to get it through subqueries using the weigthed avg formula.

Comment: Then you should at least simplify your subquery: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53d80/27